# VS Schema Compare - Exclude "AS [dbo]" from Permission Updates?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with SSDT and am attempting to sync a SQL Server 2014 database in an upper environment with objects from a DEV database. The problem is, schema compare generates all permission updates with "AS [dbo]" at the end:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[uspMyStoredProc] TO [rolMyRole]
AS [dbo];
GO
```

I do not have permission to sync the DB with the "AS [dbo]" statement at the end of each GRANT but can run each of the GRANTs without this statement. Is there any way to exclude this statement in the UPDATE script?